# How to run Rviz remotely

Tags: ros, rviz, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume that it's possible run run Rviz on a machine other than the one running the robot.  If so, how to I set the master address (the IP address of the robot) which Rviz should be subscribing to ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10343/how-to-run-rviz-remotely/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-06-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [NetworkSetup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) page has some good information on that.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on 2011-06-23**:
You should only set one. ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME are optional environment variable that sets the declared network address of a ROS Node or tool. The options are mutually exclusive

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-06-23**:
Awesome.  Setting ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME on the remote computer fixed the problem.  I notice that setting the 2D Pose Estimate using Rviz no longer works though.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set the ROS_MASTER_URI environment variable, see [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_MASTER_URI) for details.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-06-23**:
can you rostopic echo the topics you want to see on the other computer?

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-06-21**:
A can connect, but it seems that no data is being broadcast from the robot ("No messages received").  Is there anything I need to do with the parameter files to enable broadcasting of the map, for example?

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-06-21**:
you just need to be able to ping between the machines. you might also need to set the ROS_IP of the robot. Additionally you will need to sync the two machines or else you will have this problem: http://answers.ros.org/question/705/set-the-initial-pose-with-rviz

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-06-21**:
Does the robot need to have a web server installed on it (apache, etc) ?

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-02-09**:
got the same issues, ping works, but they cannot see eachother's topic/services

**Comment by [fcolecumberri](https://answers.ros.org/users/42255/fcolecumberri/) on 2021-09-20**:
Some of the problems about the "No messages received" are because you need to also set the ROS_IP and ROS_MASTER_URI inside the robot, that's because the robot (let's assume its network name is lil_robot) may receive the packets from lil_robot.local (where avahi might be able to send) but then send to lil_robot which will translate to localhost a.k.a. which is not the correct network name. so just by setting `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://lil_robot.local:11311` and `export ROS_HOSTNAME=lil_robot.local` inside the bashrc or zshrc after the `source /opt/ros/version/setup.zsh` the problem gets soved.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-08-23**:
@fcolecumberri I have this issue with my turtlebot2, I can ssh to remote PC, but when I go into Rviz on remote PC, the 2D Pose Estimate doesnt work, I can see that I am publishing to the /initialpose on the terminal but  the robot still does not move in Rviz. In the laptop physically connected to the turtlebot2, I have ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP set to the IP of the robot. In the other Remote PC I have ROS_MASTER_URI set to the IP of the robot, and ROS_IP set to the IP of the remote PC. Did I do it wrong?